# Pagespeed shows differ score vs Google chrome performance audit in lighthouse

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse

Its confusing websites owners while relying on Pagespeed insights.
Showing differ score on First Contentful Paint parameter vs lighthouse audit performance on google chrome!

Answer (score 0):

I opened a thread on Google's Page Speed fue to this problem. My guess is a mismatch between versions of Lighthouse between Google Chrome and PageSpeed but I'm still waiting an answer. I invite you to participate in the thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/WOf07ufqTHs

As far as I understand this is the official channel to open issues but they have not been responsive for the moment being. If they reply to me I'll keep you posted.

In the meanwhile I invite you to clone Lighthouse project on Github and run locally the performance tests you want to check and compare them with Google Chrome and Page Speed to see if it's a problem happening just on Page Speed or also in local.